# Programmatically setting a column name in dplyr::top_n

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation

I would like to programmatically set a column name for the `dplyr::top_n` function.

```
getSubset <- function(df, t, f) {
  df %>%
    top_n(t, wt = eval(as.name(f), envir = df))
}

data.frame(x = 1:20, y = 20:1) %>%
  getSubset(10, "x")
```

And it tells me that `Error: object 'f' not found`. I tried to play with `lazyeval` package but somehow I keep misunderstanding the concept. Could somebody push me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `top_n` uses non-standard evaluation.  It's trying to evaluate the expression `eval(as.name(f), envir = df))` in the context of the data frame `df`, and `f` doesn't exist in that environment.

One work around would be to temporarily add the desired value of `wt` to the data frame.

```
getSubset <- function(df, t, f) {
    df %>%
        mutate(.wt = eval(as.name(f), envir = df)) %>% 
        top_n(t, wt = .wt) %>% 
        select(-.wt)
}

data.frame(x = 1:20, y = 20:1) %>%
    getSubset(10, "x")
```

Another approach would be to use `interp` from the `lazyeval` package.

```
getSubset <- function(df, t, f) {
    call <- quote(df %>%
                      top_n(t, wt = .wt))
    call <- interp(call, .wt = eval(as.name(f), envir = df))
    eval(call)
}

data.frame(x = 1:20, y = 20:1) %>%
    getSubset(10, "x")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This `getSubset <- function(df, t, f) {
      df %>%
        mutate_(.dots = list(.w. = f)) %>%
        top_n(t, wt = .w.) %>%
        select(- .w.)
    }` seems to work, too. Too bad that there is no obvious way to use the method without creating additional evaluation column